# How to store multiple inputs in C++ by space

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I want the user to input a set of data followed by spaces like this:

```
Mark 23 California, USA
Susan 22 Tokyo, Japan
Anna 21 New Mexico, USA
```

I am not sure how to gather all of these separate information. I want to categorize them by name, age, location so I can access them later on by using (age[0]. age[1], etc)

So far, this is what I have

```
std::vector<std::string> name, age, location:
std::cout << "Hello, what is your Name Age Location? (separate by space) ";
std::string a, b, c;
std::cin >> a;
std::cin >> b;
std::cin >> c;
a.push_back(name);
b.push_back(age);
c.push_back(location);

std::cout << "How many people would you like to store their data? ";
int n;
std::cin >> n;

for (int a=0;a<n;a++){
    std::cout << "Please enter the Name Age Location for Person #" << n << ": ";
    std::string x, y, z;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cin >> z; //this part always gets me because the location is separated by a space and always gets cut off
    x.push_back(name);
    y.push_back(age);
    z.push_back(location);
}
```

I want to know how to be able to store the rest of the information after the 2nd white space until the end of the line. Thank you!!

Comment: You can use getline to get the rest of the input, spaces included.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ read from file parse".  You'll find something similar to yours or maybe the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the name and age values as you're doing, but then use `std::getline` to get the rest of the line, i.e. the location.

```
std::cin >> name;
std::cin >> age;
std::getline(std::cin, location); // voila!
```

Answer (score 0):

std::cin will break the line in general after a space, use std::getline() instead:

```
char buffer[256];
std::getline(buffer, size(buffer));
```